# Thunar doesn't auto-mount USB devices with default setup

Tags: thunar, removable-storage, thunar-volman

After installing and configuring [Thunar Volume Manager for Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Thunar#Thunar_Volume_Manager) it doesn't mount any USB devices automatically:

```
$ thunar
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type.
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type.
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
```

(Both messages are printed twice when inserting a single USB drive.)

[Polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) seems to be [running as expected](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions):

```
$ loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID
Id=c1
Timestamp=Tue 2013-11-19 20:54:41 GMT
TimestampMonotonic=33281762
VTNr=7
Display=:0.0
Remote=no
RemoteUser=root
Service=slim
Scope=session-c1.scope
Leader=308
Audit=0
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
Name=username
```

There are a bunch of random tips in [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111867), but at least some of them seem at odds with the wiki: `gvfs` is mentioned, although the wiki only mentions it as a requirement for [browsing remote locations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Thunar#Using_Thunar_to_browse_remote_locations).

Manual mounting works fine:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sde1 /media/foo
$ mount | grep sde1
/dev/sde1 on /media/foo type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Wondering why each squawk is printed twice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you have to [install `gvfs` and `polkit-gnome`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GVFS) to make this work. After logging out and in again Thunar supports mounting USB devices.

Comment: Archlinux here, same error messages. I have those 2 packages installed, but still does not work (sometimes it mounts it, sometimes it doesn't)

Comment: 'polkit-gnome' is called 'policykit-1-gnome' in debian stretch. But was already installed and does not fix the issue for me

Comment: By default thunar does not mount the devices automatically, that must be configured in Thunar. Of course you must have installed gvfs, polkit-gnome and udisks2.


Thunar automount Configuration: Thunar > Preferences > advanced > Volumen Configuration > Automount.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- disable thunar volume management and thunar --daemon
- `sudo apt-get install udevil`
- `echo "devmon &" >> .xinitrc`
- open thunar and usb auto-mount

Answer (score 0):

Getting usb devices to show up in thunar is messy but here is the process no matter your system configuration:

1. Dbus and Xdg stuff must be installed.
2. XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 dbus-run-session openbox-session or gnome-session (you run that in tty or put in xinitrc + startx) This loads your display environment.  If you have a login or display manager, it takes care of this step.   It is insufficient to run openbox-session since Xdg and dbus are needed as well.  3 things run in that command.
   Session type can be Wayland if compositor supports Wayland.  Openbox does not.
3. Thunar, thunar-volman and udevil must be installed computer restarted.
4. Udevil daemon thus ( udevil &) must run for a few seconds then good to launch thunar, volume management should be enabled; restart thunar if you just enabled.

Zero need for Gvfs.