# Thunar crashes when trying to unmount removable devices

Tags: thunar

After [manually mounting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101827/auto-mounting-usb-drives-in-thunar-doesnt-work) a USB device it shows up in Thunar with the standard "eject" icon next to the device name. However, clicking this invariably results in a crash with the following output:

```
$ thunar
(thunar:1906): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_source_attach: assertion 'source->context == NULL' failed
(thunar:1906): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_data: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The device is *not* unmounted. Nautilus simply informs me that it is "Unable to eject [device name] - Not authorized to perform operation," so that's clear enough. Is it necessary to configure Thunar to show such a message instead of crashing?